# Power Query how to get listed rows from the table for the Min or Max Date?

Tags: date, max, powerquery, min

Power Query how to get listed rows from the table for the Min or Max Date?[image]

Here is the code that is currently not working

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project ID", type text}, {"Activity ID", type text}, {"Activity Name", type text}, {"System Locator-g", type text}, {"Milestone-g", type text}, {"Original Duration", Int64.Type}, {"Test Work Type-g", type text}, {"MXO_WONUM", type text}, {"Start", type any}, {"Finish", type any}, {"Activity Status", type text}, {"MXO_EQUIPTAGS", type any}, {"Discipline-g", type any}, {"Restraints", type any}, {"Empty row", type any}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"MXO_WONUM"}, #"Append1 Loc Max Dump & Loc Max Dump", {"wonum"}, "Append1 Loc Max Dump & Loc Max Dump", JoinKind.LeftOuter),

#"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed Columns", {"Milestone-g"}, #"Milestone Sequence", {"Milestone-g"}, "Milestone Sequence", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Milestone Sequence" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Milestone Sequence", {"Milestone Sequence"}, {"Milestone Sequence.Milestone Sequence"}),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Milestone Sequence",{{"Milestone Sequence.Milestone Sequence", "Milestone Sequence"}}),

#"Merged Queries2" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type3", {"Component"}, #"CTM P6 Update Tab (2) - unpivoted", {"Component"}, "CTM P6 Update Tab (2) - unpivoted", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded CTM P6 Update Tab (2) - unpivoted" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries2", "CTM P6 Update Tab (2) - unpivoted", {"Test Status "}, {"CTM P6 Update Tab (2) - unpivoted.Test Status "}),
#"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded CTM P6 Update Tab (2) - unpivoted",{{"CTM P6 Update Tab (2) - unpivoted.Test Status ", "Test Status"}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns2", {"Component", "Milestone-g", "Milestone Sequence", "Activity Status", "Activity ID", "Activity Name"}, {{"Grouped", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(#"Renamed Columns2",{"Grouped",Order.Ascending}),1), type table}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get the rows that are either the min or max date of the Grouped column?

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"YourPriorStepNameGoesHere", each ([Grouped] = List.Min(#"YourPriorStepNameGoesHere"[Grouped]) or [Grouped] =List.Max(#"YourPriorStepNameGoesHere"[Grouped])))
```

Edit per question:

to do this by Component, best way is to group on Component then expand. I am assuming one row per date, otherwise I'd have to do it another way

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Component", type text}, {"Grouped", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Component"}, {{"data", each 
    Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Grouped", Order.Ascending}}),1) &
    Table.LastN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Grouped", Order.Ascending}}),1) 
    , type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Grouped"}, {"Grouped"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

Comment: Yeah!!! This is it. I just wanted to select rows either min or max. It works! Thank you so much.

Comment: I forgot about one more think in my question. My example has only 1 component listed. How to modify that query for multiple different components listed in the Component Column?

Comment: The code I provided worked for the sample image given.  Can you get the code provided to work with the sample data?  Then its an issue in how you modified the code.  You need to tell us what error you are getting and post all your code, not just a snip-- is the code working but not evaluating correctly? Is entering the code itself generating an error Are all the columns in the GroupRow code present in your table (like column Grouped)

Comment: code is long I'm not sure how to paste it here

Comment: Edit your original question and paste into bottom

Comment: I think I did it. So everything works till the last step #"Grouped Rows". Looking for all components with MIN date listed only.

Comment: Is there a column named Grouped, which is what the last step is looking for ? My code used that because there was a column with that name. I dont see that column in your code anywhere

Comment: Yes. The "Grouped" column is a column of start date. I changed it for "Grouped" after Table grouped

Comment: Sorry, I cant tell whats wrong between my sample working and your modification of it not working.